# Deploying to openshift WildFly

Tags: java, maven, build-process, build-automation, wildfly-8

I am using JSF, EJB, WildFly, maven and MySQL db to develop an app. I have a development environment for my project (db in the cloud and a local WildFly server). I want to deploy my app to the QA environment which is an openshift WildFly with MySQL cartridge. To deploy the app I have to just commit my war file to the git repository, not big deal. But to build this war file I have to change my persistence.xml, web.xml and compile all again in order to get my app working in QA environment. Is there any way to automate this process? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved. Solution: maven profiles

Comment: It will be good to others facing the problem if you can provide an elaborate answer.